# How to access the stored credentials (PasswordVault?) on Win7 and Win8?

Tags: c#, security, passwordvault

I just discovered that Win8 has a section on the Control Panel called *User Accounts and Family Safely* with *Credential Manager*. I'd like to access the credentials stored in there (not to **retrieve** the passwords but to use them as tokens for a login). So, basically, I'd like to get a piggy-back ride on already installed software.

The closest to a solution has been suggested in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538367/using-credenumerate-to-pull-webcredentials) and it's not **that** close.

1. **Where do I find the assembly for *Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault*?** I've been googling for two hours but I only get information on app development while I'll be targeting desktop.
2. **Is there a way to resolve access to the pre-stored credentials for both Win7 and Win8?** I fear a little bit that the vault facility has been drastically remodeled in Win8, making it impossible to target both platforms at once.

Comment: The assembly for `PasswordVault` resides in `Windows.winmd`.

Comment: I have nothing staring with *Windows* when I try to add references to an assembly. What could be wrong?!

Comment: In the _Reference Manager_, do you see a section called _Windows_, just between _COM_ and _Browse_?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Nope... I've got: .NET / COM / Projects / Browse / Recent. That's all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Reference Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh708954%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> In the desktop projects the Core tab doesn’t appear by default. You
>   can add the Windows Runtime by opening the shortcut menu for the
>   project node, choosing **Unload Project**, adding the following snippet,
>   and re-opening the project (on the project node choose **Reload**
>    **Project**). When you invoke the **Reference Manager** dialog box, the Core
>   tab appears.
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>     <TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```
>
> Make sure to check the Windows box on this tab. You should then be
>   able to use WinRT elements.

Comment: This is not going to fly for Win7, is it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Probably, you'll get an exception at runtime: `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.`

Comment: for win8 and full how-to details see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457335/How-to-call-WinRT-APIs-from-NET-desktop-apps

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same issue and found out that there is no simple answer anywhere.

This is what I found:

1. You need to unload the project and add the `TargetPlatformVersion` as mentioned above.
2. Add the reference: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Annotated\Windows.winmd`
3. Also add the reference: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`

Answer (score 3):

You can use wrapped [Credential Management package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/). It's an open-source project. I checked it in Windows 7 and it works right.

In order to save your data use following code:

```
    Credential saved = new Credential("username", "password", "MyApp", CredentialType.Generic);
    saved.PersistanceType = PersistanceType.LocalComputer;
    saved.Save();
```

And to load your data use:

```
    Credential credential = new Credential { Target = "MyApp", Type = CredentialType.Generic };
    credential.Load();
```