# How to verify that PasswordVault encrypts the credentials on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: security, testing, windows-phone-8, passwords, windows-phone-8.1

Windows (Phone) 8.1 has a Credential Locker called [PasswordVault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault) that you can use to store and encrypt credentials.

I saw from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813370/how-to-access-the-stored-credentials-passwordvault-on-win7-and-win8) you are able to access or get the credentials via the [Reference Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh708954(v=vs.110).aspx) on Windows 8. So, I am looking for something similar, but on the Windows Phone (8.1).

**Question:** How do you verify that the credentials inside the `PaswordVault` on the Windows Phone are actually encrypted?

*Purpose: I don't like to take things on face value, I want to verify that the credentials are really encrypted.*

Answer (score 0):

Password vault is dedicated space for your credentials and it cannot be accesed from any other application.

There is code for storing credentials:

```
var vault = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault();
        vault.Add(new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential("Your_App_Name", userName, password));
```

Here is method for retreiving credentials:

```
public static Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential GetCredentialFromLocker()
    {
        try
        {
            Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential credential = null;
            var vault = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault();
            var credentialList = vault.FindAllByResource("Your_App_Name");

            if (credentialList.Count > 0)
            {
                if (credentialList.Count == 1)
                {
                    credential = credentialList[0];
                }
            }

            return credential;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I can already store and retrieve credentials using the `PasswordVault` this is however not the question. The question is how do you verify that those passwords inside the `PasswordVault` actuality are encrypted!