# Access Windows Credentials in Credential Manager

Tags: c#, security, credential-manager

Using the `Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault` class, I can access the passwords stored under "Web Credentials" in the Windows Credential Manager:

```
using System;
using Windows.Security.Credentials;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
        foreach (var cred in vault.RetrieveAll()) {
            cred.RetrievePassword();
            Console.WriteLine("Resource: {0}", cred.Resource);
            Console.WriteLine("UserName: {0}", cred.UserName);
            Console.WriteLine("Password: {0}", cred.Password);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there's a way to retrieve the credentials stored under "Windows Credentials" instead.

Comment: To add the reference to `Windows.Security` in a desktop app, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813370/how-to-access-the-stored-credentials-passwordvault-on-win7-and-win8

Comment: Windows does not store the actual password, it is usually some type of hash of the password.  The only way to get the clear text Windows password for a user is to capture it when the user types it during logon.  For this you would need to write a Windows Credential provider.

Comment: @MohitA: I'm talking about something completely different here. I want to retrieve a password that **I stored in the Credential Manager** under Windows Credentials, I don't want to sniff some other user's password.

Comment: Did this solution work for you in IIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Nuget library called CredentialManagement http://nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/ 
from the answer here: [Retrieve Credentials from Windows Credentials Store using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741424/retrieve-credentials-from-windows-credentials-store-using-c-sharp)

works perfectly

```
        var cm = new Credential();
        cm.Target = "mycredentialname";

        if (!cm.Exists())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("cm is null");
        }
        cm.Load();
        Console.WriteLine("Password: " + cm.Password);
        Console.WriteLine("Username: " + cm.Username);
```